# Send chrome tab from w7 laptop to w7 HTPC? (Like with iPad to AppleTV)

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, android, media, htpc

For the last couple days I've been trying to figure out how to get open tabs syncing between chrome installs on different computers to no avail. (if it's supposed to work the way I think it should, that is.)

I have a laptop that I do all my web browsing on. Once in a while I'll come across some video that's worthy of the big-screen and the surround sound and want to open that tab (or media) on the HTPC.

It'd be nice if I could just 'Right click > Send to HTPC' and it opens up there with no further hassle. But even opening chrome on the HTPC and finding all my current tabs waiting would be fine. Alas, open tabs syncing doesn't seem to actually open tabs on other devices for me.

Has anyone come up with a way to accomplish anything similar?

Thanks all!

Comment: Not if the open tabs are actually supposed to open themselves on the 2nd device. I can find them in the "Recent Tabs", but they have to be opened manually.

Comment: So you want an extension to 'push' webpages to other computer when you click a button?

Comment: That'd be quite spiffy, yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tab Auto Sync](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-auto-sync/pglfmdocdcdahjhgcbpjmbglpeenmmef) syncs in real-time your open tabs in Chrome (as long as you are signed in - which you currently are):

> Real-time synchronization of tabs and windows between computers.
>
> > Closing chrome will save your tabs.  To remove tabs, close the tabs.  If you close the last tab, chrome will close and next time you will be shown the new tab page.

In my test, this worked exactly as you want, you don't even need to use a button - you just close your tabs on one computer, they open on the other (when you open Chrome).

Comment: I've tried Tab Auto Sync and Real-time Tab Sync. I've found neither of them work properly. =(

Comment: @Justin How does Tab Auto Sync not work? It worked fine for me. Just close the window on one device, it opens on the other (when you open chrome)...